# Plotting points as 3D spheres using Plotly

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have data in the form of tables, which I wish to plot as 3D spheres - where the point would represent a sphere of radius r = value of the point.
Eg: `point=4.7` --> sphere of radius 4.7

Example:

Table 1, would result in 15 spheres, at say height `z=1`:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.5 | 4.9 | 4.9 | 4.9 | 4.7 |
| 4.5 | 4.8 | 4.8 | 4.8 | 4.8 |
| 4.3 | 4.7 | 4.7 | 4.9 | 4.9 |

Table 2, would result in another 15 spheres shifted "upward", at say height `z=2`:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.3 | 4.7 | 4.7 | 4.9 | 4.7 |
| 4.4 | 4.8 | 4.8 | 4.8 | 4.7 |
| 4.5 | 4.9 | 4.9 | 4.9 | 4.8 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this question is missing some detail - please include some code which is a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edits. I don't really have a "reproducible" example, as I am trying to figure out the method to produce the plot itself in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to figure this out, the key idea was to use the `marker`  parameter, which in-turn has a `size` property (ref: [plotly documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.scatter3d.html#plotly.graph_objects.scatter3d.Marker.size))

Example Code:

Convert the dataframes into list of numpy arrays, using the Pandas `to_numpy()` method and then flattening each array using the NumPy `flatten()` method.

For example: `arrList.append(df.iloc[0:5,:].to_numpy().flatten())`.

NOTE: My data also contains blanks in the form of "-".

```
arrList =
[array([2.5, 2.7, 3.9, 3.8, 3.9, 2.6, 2.5, 2.5, 3.9, 3.7, 2.4, 2.6, 2.4, 4,
        3.9, 2.5, 2.3, 2.3, 3.9, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7, 3.7,
        3.7, 3.8, 3.9], dtype=object),
 array([3.8, 3.9, 2.7, 3, 2.6, 3.9, 3.3, 2.9, 2.7, 3.8, 4, 3.6, 3.9, 3.8,
        3.9, 3.7, 3.8, 4, 3.9, 3.6, 3.8, 3.9, '-', '-', '-', 3.9, 3.9, '-',
        '-', '-'], dtype=object)]
```

Since the `size` property assigns a size in pixels, I have defined a method to "increase" the pixels by x-times (3x in my case), for float and/or int values in my data

```
def sizeMask(s):
    sphereSize = lambda s: s if isinstance(s, float) else s if isinstance(s, int) else 0.0
    vec_sphereSize = np.vectorize(sphereSize)
    return vec_sphereSize(s)
```

```
sizeList = [sizeMask(arr)*3.0 for arr in arrList]
sizeList =
[array([ 7.5,  8.1, 11.7, 11.4, 11.7,  7.8,  7.5,  7.5, 11.7, 11.1,  7.2,
         7.8,  7.2, 12. , 11.7,  7.5,  6.9,  6.9, 11.7, 11.1, 11.4, 11.7,
        10.8, 11.1, 11.4, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 11.4, 11.7]),
 array([11.4, 11.7,  8.1,  9. ,  7.8, 11.7,  9.9,  8.7,  8.1, 11.4, 12. ,
        10.8, 11.7, 11.4, 11.7, 11.1, 11.4, 12. , 11.7, 10.8, 11.4, 11.7,
         0. ,  0. ,  0. , 11.7, 11.7,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ])]
```

Finally, the plot is generated as follows:

```
x = np.asarray([[i]*5 for i in range(1,7)]).flatten()
y = np.asarray([np.arange(1,6)]*6).flatten()

data=[]
for i,arr in enumerate(arrList):
    data.append(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y,
                             z=np.asarray([i+1]*30),
                             mode='markers',
                             marker=dict(size=sizeList[i], showscale=False)))
    
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
```

[image: Plotting points as 3D spheres using Plotly]